# How can I send text from an iPhone to a PC?

Tags: iphone, windows

I don't have an email client set up on my PC.

I'm looking for a simple way to send some text from my iPhone to my PC.

I could use Dropbox, or I could email my Dropbox account.
But each of these methods requires a lot of effort.

Ideally, I'd like something where I can paste and tap send and have it pop up on my PC.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a gmail or hotmail account as these have a web interface, and send the text as email to said account.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, you'll need *some* process running on your PC which will listen for incoming messages.

Email is the simplest solution, primarily because iOS has "send via email" integration built into it.

Another option is Twitter. iOS 5 also has Twitter support built into it. You could setup a Twitter account on your Windows computer and have it follow your main account, and use Twitter to send information to it. That will require some sort of a Windows Twitter client which will look for incoming messages.

But if you want the fastest method, I think your best bet is Instant Messaging. Install an IM client on your PC, and then on your iPhone. Personally, I would use http://www.google.com/talk/ but http://aim.com would also work.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a mobile-friendly pastebin to share text between my iPhone and PC. None of the pastebin-type sites seem to be formatted nicely for mobile devices.

In the end, I found something better: **Naver Memo synchronizes notes between the web and iPhone application.** Optionally, you can install a PC client that is very similar to the post-it application that comes with Windows 7. Caveat: you have to create a Naver account and navigate Korean menus. Naver is like Korea's version of Google^^

- First install the [Naver memo app](http://mobile.naver.com/service/memo). Link to [iPhone version](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id451086610?mt=8).
- Here's a link to the [Naver Memo mobile web interface](http://m.me.naver.com/mobile/main.nhn?vMode=m).
- You can also see/edit your memos on the right side of Naver's [personalized portal](http://me.naver.com/index.nhn).
- Optionally install the [Windows PC client](http://me2.do/Gr5EJj) for instant, super easy note syncronization!

---

Alternatively, for sending short bits of text from my PC to iPhone, I found an online QR code generator and QR code scanner works very well. I suppose if your PC has a camera, you could get it to work in the other direction, too.

- Recommended QR code generator: http://goqr.me/
- Recommended QR code reader app: [Red Laser](http://redlaser.com/).
- Recommended [PC QR code reader](http://www.dansl.net/blog/?p=256).

Answer (score -1):

There's an app for that! 
I found the perfect solution, download 
Lazy Text iOS app. Works for any desktop computer, you have to be in same network. 
And at the moment is FREE.

Comment: How is it better than the other apps listed here? and can you say wha it does not just give a name